# Swift iOS - Need to get the value of a stored cookie from UIWebView and use it as a variable

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, uiwebview

In a Swift project I have a varible that is a URL

```
var myUrl = "https://myurl.com/pathto/script.php"
```

I need to get the value of a cookie from my UIWebView that is automatically accepted with

```
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookieAcceptPolicy = HTTPCookie.AcceptPolicy.always
```

I have to get the value of this cookie, which has a name that starts with text that never changes but ends with a bunch of random numbers that are generated for each user.  So I need to check for a cookie that starts with "my_cookie_name_" - and can have any random string of numbers after that.

I then need to take the value of that cookie and place that value in my myUrl variable like this

```
var myUrl = "https://myurl.com/pathto/script.php?id=(COOKIEVALUEHERE)"
```

I'm not the most technically advanced and I cannot seem to find a solution to this.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The linked duplicate shows how to retrieve a cookie with Swift.

Comment: It is not a duplicate of my question...

Comment: So please [edit] your question to show your attempt.  The linked duplicate shows how to retrieve a cookie from the shared cookie storage in Swift.  After retrieving the cookie, all you need to do is append its value to the URL.